# Mutation-immunity in Luria-Delbruck experiment

Tags: microbiology, bacteriology, mutations

If experiments like those of Luria and Delbruck on *E. coli* and T1 phage are the main source of our confidence in the mutation-immunity model, is it then highly unlikely that there are other types of bacteria for which an encounter with a phage is the mutagenic (or immunity-conferring) event?

Are the two possibilities in principle mutually exclusive?

Comment: No. There was a recent surprising paper on a bacterial adaptive immune system. I cannot find it, unfortunately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Surprisingly, there is an adaptive immune system in prokaryotes. This is still widely unknown. The newest review is

S. Al-Attar, E. R. Westra et al: *Clustered regularly interspaced short palindromic repeats (CRISPRs): the hallmark of an ingenious antiviral defense mechanism in prokaryotes.* In: *Biological chemistry.* 392, 4, April 2011, 277–289. doi:10.1515/BC.2011.042. PMID 21294681. (Review).

Cited from abstract:

> Many prokaryotes contain the recently discovered defense system
>   against mobile genetic elements. This defense system contains a unique
>   type of repetitive DNA stretches, termed Clustered Regularly
>   Interspaced Short Palindromic Repeats (CRISPRs). CRISPRs consist of
>   identical repeated DNA sequences (repeats), interspaced by highly
>   variable sequences referred to as spacers. The spacers originate from
>   either phages or plasmids and comprise the prokaryotes' 'immunological
>   memory'. CRISPR-associated (cas) genes encode conserved proteins that
>   together with CRISPRs make-up the CRISPR/Cas system, responsible for
>   defending the prokaryotic cell against invaders.

and

> An application of the CRISPR/Cas system is the immunization of
>   industry-relevant prokaryotes (or eukaryotes) against mobile-genetic
>   invasion. In addition, the high variability of the CRISPR spacer
>   content can be exploited for phylogenetic and evolutionary studies.
>   Despite impressive progress during the last couple of years, the
>   elucidation of several fundamental details will be a major challenge
>   in future research.